# PhantomJS fails with 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require'

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am working in Ubuntu 14.04. I have done `npm install phantomjs` and now I am simply trying to screenshot a webpage, [using the simple example in the docs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).

This is my script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Now I am trying to run it with `phantomjs --debug=true --ssl-protocol=any github.js`.

However it fails with `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm not sure if I need to allow outgoing/ingoing network connections.

This is the error output in full: http://pastebin.com/raw/7p0nSeJx

Comment: Debug log looks ok, have you checked the working directory for `github.png`? Is it writable for the user from which the script is run?

Comment: It is, yes. I see both a `TypeError` and a `ReferenceError` in the debug log, would you expect that?

Comment: What is PhantomJS version? Does it actually generate screenshot? (More on errors later)

Comment: You have to be more specific. Does the error come from the page context or from the outer context. I mean if you replace the `page.open(...)` call with `phantom.exit()`, does it still appear?